# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am using a program called dawg  which depends on boost library. I need to run the program on the cluster where I do not have root access.  While trying to run the program it returns error as :

```
/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/dawg_new/my_build/bin/dawg: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed the boost 1.65.1 package manually and have put it in the  '.bashrc' file as following:

```
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/boost_1_65_1/lib/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

the file ' libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1' exist in the ' /home/masih/Baterial_simulator/boost_1_65_1/lib/lib ' but still I get the  error.

I have also tried to include the boost package information while configuring the package by putting the following lines in the 'CMakeLists.txt'

```
SET (BOOST_ROOT "/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/boost_1_65_1/lib")
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/boost_1_65_1/lib/include")
SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/boost_1_65_1/lib/lib")
```

The installation completes without any error but trying to run the program returns the same error again.
The cluster is using RedHat OS.

Comment: »» #export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.. «« : What is the hash mark ( # ) doing in that line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the path of directory where your program is running.

For Example:
Below line will direct library-path to your current/program directory.
if already set then use : `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/dawg_new/my_build/bin/dawg:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Note:** This command only work when  libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1 is installed in system lib path.
If not working then direct your library path to path of your running program.

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/boost_1_65_1/lib/lib:/home/masih/Baterial_simulator/dawg_new/my_build/bin/dawg
```